# Prevent auto-closing windows batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a batch file that enables me to run multiple python files at the same time and it is ok at this point.

```
@ECHO ON

start python "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Pop1.py"
ECHO Running Pop1
start python "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Pop2.py"
ECHO Running Pop2

PAUSE
```

But there is a problem for me, when the python file executed, I need to follow the print statements to follow the program. When I execute the batch the console windows for both the python files disappears quickly. How can I keep them open to be able to follow the execution of python files?

Comment: try : `pause >nul`

Comment: After `start python` line or what?

Comment: Do you want to start it in two diff console?

Comment: Yes, two different console is OK. All what I need is to keep the console open -that is related to the execution of the python file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to include `-i` after python

```
@ECHO off

start python -i "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Pop1.py"
start python -i "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Pop2.py"
```